# Как с помощью css сделать так, чтобы при наведении на картинку у нее появлялся такой слой как на третьем элементе?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здесь есть 8 картинок и при наведении на каждую должен появляться слой

Comment: Какой "такой" слой?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}

div:hover:after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  z-index: 9;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/1278966/12202/i/950/depositphotos_122027768-stock-photo-beautiful-vertical-landscape-of-rocky.jpg">
</div>
```